# Linq, Left Out Join Issue

Tags: c#, linq

I am carrying out a left outer join using linq. The right object has 42 records, the left object has 2 records. The result should be one successful join, and the remaindered of the right object.

(Error Message follows after the code.)

```
    private async Task PopulateDatasourceOfPlanToKill()
    {
        _killPlansRepository = new KillPlansRepository();
        _factoryRegistrations = new FactoryRegistrationsRepository();

        var plans =  _killPlansRepository.Get();
        var registrations =  _factoryRegistrations.GetTodaysRegistrations();

        try
        {

            var query = plans.GroupJoin(
                registrations, plan => plan.Id, reg => reg.PlanIdentity, (plan, reg) => new { killPlans = plan, registrations = reg})
                .SelectMany(plan => plan.registrations.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            ,(plan,Reg) => new
                            {
                                plan.killPlans.DateKilled
                                ,plan.killPlans.FarmCode
                                ,plan.killPlans.HouseNumber  
                                ,plan.killPlans.Quantity 
                                ,plan.killPlans.Age                                          
                                ,plan.killPlans.BirdSexCode                                          
                                ,plan.killPlans.EstimatedWeightG                                          
                                ,Reg.RegDateTime
                            });

            var bob = new BindingSource();
            bob.Add(query);

            bsKillPlans.DataSource = bob;
                //.OrderBy(r => r.FarmCode)
                //.ThenByDescending(r => r.HouseNumber);


        }
        catch (Exception oops)
        {
            //Todo: logger
            MessageBox.Show($"Can't load the daily kill plans. \rPlease contact the service desk on ???. \rTechnical: {oops.Message}");
        }
    }
```

The error message returned is: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Help!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could indicate exactly where your exception is thrown.

Comment: What happens with `Reg.RegDateTime` when `Reg == null`.

Comment: Matt, good point! At SelectMany.

Comment: Ivan, I think it goes bang! ;) Not sure though how to handle when RegDateTime is null. :(

Comment: `RegDateTime` wouldn't cause that problem. More likely your problem is when `Reg` is null. It's not clear how you want to handle that situation. You could try `Reg?.RegDateTime`. It could also be possible that `plan` and or `killPlans` are null for at least one of your items.

Comment: Will try this in AM and respond back. Thanks guys! :D

Comment: Guys, the Null-Conditional Operator worked. I am getting a record set back. Thanks you for taking the time to answer my question. Much appreciated. :)